# Repeating a VBA / Excel macro across multiple work books

Tags: vba, excel

I have 20 excel workbooks - each identical except that they work with different data. I often need to refine and update the formulae, which I then copy from a source workbook to each of the other workbooks in turn.

I use VBA to record a macro (which I know is not that elegant) to copy and paste the changes required. This is fine, but it's tedious to have to copy the macro 20 times, changing the target workbook name each time.  My preferred solution is to automate it by setting up a loop and calling the macro for each target in turn.

I am new to macros, and am struggling with the right syntax for this.

I've tried the following, but it does not work.  I get a "Object Variable not set" error message, which i don't really understand and can't resolve.

```
Sub New()
'
Dim i As Integer
Dim target As Workbook
target(1) = "Workbook1.xlsx"
target(2) = "Workbook2.xlsx"
'etc for the other countries
For i = 1 To 20
Update
Next i
End Sub

Sub Update()
' Update macro copies updated cells from workbook Country A.xlsx to target workbook
Windows("Country A.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Tax").Select
Rows("17:26").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows(target(i)).Activate
Sheets("Tax").Select
Range("A17").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' Etc for other changes required
End Sub
```

Any help on what i'm missing would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sub Update is not "seeing" the variable **i**.  Consider:

```
Sub New()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim target As Workbook
    target(1) = "Workbook1.xlsx"
    target(2) = "Workbook2.xlsx"
    'etc for the other countries
    For i = 1 To 20
        Update (i)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Update(i As Integer)
    ' Update macro copies updated cells from workbook Country A.xlsx to target workbook
    Windows("Country A.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Tax").Select
    Rows("17:26").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(target(i)).Activate
    Sheets("Tax").Select
    Range("A17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ' Etc for other changes required
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gary's student. Unfortunately this is still giving me a "91" error - Object variable not set on the target(1) = "Workbook1.xlsx" line.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few different things, i've found a solution to avoid the problems with the above code. It involves setting up the names of the various target worksheets in an array.

The code below works

```
Sub Newtest()
'
Dim target As String
Dim targetwb(1 To 2) As String
targetwb(1) = "Workbook3.xlsx"
targetwb(2) = "Workbook4.xlsx"
'
For i = 1 To 2
    target = targetwb(i)
    Test1 (target)
Next i

End Sub

Sub Test1(target)
'
' Copies updated cells from workbook Country A.xlsx to target workbook
'
Windows("Country A.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Tax").Select
Rows("17:26").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows(target).Activate
Sheets("Tax").Select
Range("A17").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'
End Sub
```